# CKEDITOR 4.5.4 widget drag and drop multiplies widget instance

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

I have a problem with drag-n-dropping simple ckeditor widget. For a second (and more) drop, CKEDITOR fires paste event twice and duplicates widget in editor. This feature/bug has become active after I've upgraded it to 4.5.4 version. It was working fine on lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

Update version to 4.5.5 helped me.